# Using 2 Custom UITableViewCells on a UITableView and a different NSArray in each

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I just started programming in Objective C about 7 weeks ago and am current facing this challenge.

I am making a simple e-commerce app with product objects in two classes (Bicycle and Accessory).  The user can select objects to add to the cart (subclasses ChosenBicycle and ChosenAccessory).

These objects are passed to ShoppingCartViewController, which has two custom cells on a UITableView.

**What is the best way to add the chosen objects onto my UITableView?**

I was thinking a different array for each uniquely named cell, or would it be one cartArray (not sure how I would distribute in cellForRow... if the object attributes are from two different classes?)?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: `These objects are passed to ShoppingCartViewController, which has two custom cells on a UITableView.` 

Why are you using two cells, please add some code to make it more clear.

Comment: @VinayJain I passed two different arrays from BicycleViewController and AccessoryViewController to this ShoppingCartViewController.  Bicycle and Accessory objects have different attributes.  I thought it might make sense to keep them on separate cells/arrays (I am using different labels for the different attributes on each cell).

Comment: If you are using classes then to distinguish between objects you can use the `class` property of the object and check for what is the class of the current object

Answer (score 0):

You should'nt really need the ChosenBicycle and ChosenAccessory subclasses. You can just have a mutable array to which you can add objects of Bicycle or Accessory whenever the user adds them to the cart. Pass this array to the ShoppingCartTableViewController.

For the table view, use a single custom cell.If the UI(User Interface) of the cell for a Bicycle is different from that of an Accessory, then add the UI components required for both into the same cell and show/hide the UI components depending on the product(Bicycle/Accessory) that cell contains by changing the alpha values of the UIViews corresponding to the UI component.

Comment: For your first point: I initially tried to do that in ShoppingCartViewController's viewDidLoad (but commented it out as it seemed to be making app crash).  

Is the code something like this (passed in my 2 arrays, combined the objects into 2 array):

    self.shoppingCartArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.theChosenBike.passTheBikeArray];
    [self.shoppingCartArray addObject:testAccessory];

I think it crashes when the testAccessory is nil (meaning the user only chose a bike to add to the cart, no accessory).

Will try 2nd suggestion, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of ShoppingCartViewController, you can keep a check for the object type and populate the cell accordingly.

```
    if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[Bicycle class]]) {

}
   else {

}
```

Comment: thanks, I was thinking an if..else.. should work but couldn't think of what kind of logic to use.  Will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

create a single `NSMutableArray` lets name it cartArray for your cart

Add to it the objects of your two classes.

Now in cellForRowAtIndexPath check for the class of the object :

```
Class currentObjectClass = [[cartArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].class];

if (currentObjectClass == "BicycleClass"){
    //write code for Bicycle cell
}
else {
    //write code for Accessory cell
}
return cell;
```